# Invoke a public method with no parameters using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, user-controls

I have a method in my user control:

```
public string ControleIdContainer()
{
   string abc = "Hello";
   return abc;
}
```

Now I want to call this method on my Page using reflection. I have tried this but it is not working:

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/UserControls"));
FileInfo[] controlsInfo = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.ascx");
foreach (var item in controlsInfo)
{
    var customControl = LoadControl(string.Format("~/UserControls/{0}", item));
    var controlType = customControl.GetType();
    var controlClientScript = controlType.GetMethod("ControleIdContainer").Invoke(null,null);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should use an interface like `IHaveControleIdContainer` - then you can just do an `as` cast, test for null, and call the method.

Comment: Echoing @default.kramer ... yes, always avoid reflection wherever you can. It should be a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of [`MethodInfo.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx) is the instance on which you want to invoke the method.  Pass `customControl` as the first parameter instead of `null` and it should work.

Comment: its working but as u can see i am calling it in a loop so next time it gives me error "Object refrence not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: @HaseebKhan: That could be for a variety of reasons.  Is `customControl` null?  Is `GetMethod` returning a null `MethodInfo`?  Try adding some checks for `null` in that code to narrow down where the problem is.

Answer (score 4):

There are many reasons for getting errors

**1. REASON 1**

You haven't given the class instance inside the `Invoke` as first parameter. The code should be

```
var controlClientScript = controlType.GetMethod("MethodName").Invoke(classInstance,null);
```

**2. REASON 2**

There can be multiple methods with the same name of your method(Overloaded method). In such cases, it will show the below error.

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException' occurred. Ambiguous match
>   found.

So you need to specify that you are calling the method which have no parameters. Use the below code.

```
MethodInfo mInfo = classInstance.GetType().GetMethods().FirstOrDefault
                (method => method.Name == "MethodName"
                && method.GetParameters().Count() == 0);
mInfo.Invoke(classInstance, null);
```

**3. REASON 3**

If you are using `Type.GetType` to get the class type, if the class is in another assembly, `Type.GetType` will be null. In such cases you have loop through the `Assemblies`. Use the code below.

```
Type type = GetTheType("MyNameSpace.MyClass");
object objMyClass = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
MethodInfo mInfo = ojMyClass.GetType().GetMethods().FirstOrDefault
                   (method => method.Name == "MethodName"
                   && method.GetParameters().Count() == 0);
mInfo.Invoke(objMyClass, null);
```

and `GetTheType` method is here. The parameter to `GetTheType` must be a [Fully Qualified Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
 public object GetTheType(string strFullyQualifiedName)
 {
        Type type = Type.GetType(strFullyQualifiedName);
        if (type != null)
            return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        foreach (var asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            type = asm.GetType(strFullyQualifiedName);
            if (type != null)
                return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        }
        return null;
 }
```